# Stretching An Image in Tableview

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimage

What else is needed to display image to full tableview width?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"balloon_2.png"]; 
[image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:13]; 
cell.image = image;
```

Answer (score 1):

stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight: returns a new UIImage.
You need to do something like

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"balloon_2.png"]; 
UIImage *strImage = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:13]; 
cell.image = strImage;
```

... or just assign the result of the message to cell.image right away.

See also: [UIImage reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:)

Comment: Changed this and now get exception when running:
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UICGColor stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x529900'
Arguments don't seem wrong though?